# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: on WebSphere Liberty

Tags: java, datasource, jndi, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to use a datasource configurated as a JNDI on a WebSphere Application Server Liberty however I'm getting the follwoing error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp/master
```

The configuration for the datasource in Websphere application server is:

```
<dataSource commitOrRollbackOnCleanup="commit" id="jdbc/myapp/master" jdbcDriverRef="ojdbc7" jndiName="jdbc/myapp/master">
        <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe" oracleRACXARecoveryDelay="0" password="xxxxxxxx" user="app_master"> 
         </properties.oracle>
         <connectionManager maxPoolSize="50"/>
    </dataSource>
```

The connection to database is made via this code inside a servlet (jndi=jdbc/myapp/master):

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(jndi);
            setConnection(ds.getConnection());
            System.out.println(getConnection().toString() );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java:comp/env` requires resource reference. You have following options to solve that:

1) Use resource injection - so instead of looking up it directly  (via InitialContext) just add the following in your servlet class

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/myapp/master", name="jdbc/myapp/master")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

2) Define resource reference in your `web.xml` like

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>my datasource</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/myapp/master</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

or you can create just reference also via annotation in the code.

3) Use direct JNDI, without reference (not a Java EE best practice)

```
 DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("jdbc/myapp/master");
```

Comment: I'm using the 3rd option and it seems it's not working. What is strange is it has worked with remote servers and know after changing to local I'm having troubles. A JDBC connection to the same DB works as expected.

Comment: @SocketM you aren't using the 3rd option exactly because your `initCtx` has the prefix `initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");` on it. So in your original question really you are doing a lookup on `java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp/master`. Instead, you want to just do a lookup on `jdbc/myapp/master` (i.e. drop the `java:comp/env` prefix)

Comment: @Gas can you please tell me why option 3 is not recommended?

Comment: @SocketM The advantage of an indirect JNDI lookup (resource ref) is that it makes your applications easier to maintain as you not hardcode jndi names in the app. If the actual JNDI name of a resource changes, no changes need to be made to your application. You can just change binding in the configuration. In case of Liberty `<application-bnd><resource-ref name="jdbc/mydb" binding-name="jdbc/proddb" /></application-bnd>`. But it was more important in tWAS than Liberty. So maybe I'll change the 'not recommended' to 'not a best practice' :-)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is already stated in the other answer, you should also check that you have enabled the jndi-1.0 feature.  This is a common cause of lookups not working in Liberty.

For example, in server.xml,

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
  ... other features that you use
</featureManager>
```

And if this, too, is not enough to get it working, you should also check the configuration of resources upon which the dataSource depends, such as the jdbcDriver with id of ojdbc7 which is referenced in the config snippet that you provided.

Comment: jndi feature is enabled. jdbcDriver is configurated to run with ojdbc7. Thank you for you input.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. Man, having to look up such simple solutions always makes me feel a little dumber inside...